# Login with facebook button with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm working on an app that uses Parse backend, and I've implemented Facebook login following [Parse's tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios). I am not using `PFLoginViewController` provided by Parse, only the login method calls to the `PFFacebookUtils` class. The implementation works well.

What I now need is the 'login with Facebook' button. Since I'm not using `LoginViewController`, I can't use the `loginView` property that would give me the button. Nor can I use the `FBLoginView` from Facebook SDK as the view neither surfaces the button nor allows one to override the method that is called when the button is clicked.

What is the best way to extract the button from existing SDKs - either Parse or Facebook - so that the button is always visually up to date?